# BSOD When Running Most Programs That Have The Option of a Microphone

Tags: windows-xp, audio, bsod, microphone

The problem is that whenever I open a program that involves something with a microphone, my computer blue screens, with the file causing the trouble being *sfng32.sys*.

I have looked up this problem online, and have never found a solution.

I first got this error when trying to install an audio driver so I could record my PC's sound, which ended up disabling my audio, having to fix the problem, and then that's when the blue screen problem came about.

Fraps oddly works, but anything else doesn't: Team Fortress 1 & 2, Microsoft Expression (screen capture software), etc.
I don't know if downloading a new *sfng32.sys* will fix the problem, as I don't want to cause even more trouble.

Here is a *[DxDiag.txt](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92643584/DxDiag.txt)* because you'll probably need it.

Comment: it sounds like a bad audio driver.  did you get the audio driver from the sound card manufacturer?

Comment: No, it just came with the computer. My sound still works, just mostly anything that involves a microphone crashes.

Answer (score 1):

Install a new sound card driver.  If that doesn't work, install an old version.

If that doesn't work, you likely have a hardware problem, in which case you can probably get away with a new sound card.  There are plenty of cheap USB dongles that would meet your needs.